# how to obtain the pipe symbol on the keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I was told to get the ¦ pipe symbol you press and hold the right alt key then the key next to the 1 on the top row of keys.

But this doesn't work for me, yet the keyboard clearly mentions this symbol.

another website  said it's the same as | but as you can see it's clearly not.

Can anyone explain why I can't get this symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold `SHIFT` + the key with `|` (on my QWERTY keyboard, `|` on the key looks like `¦`).

Comment: Maybe posting details about your keyboard, operating system, used layouts will help.